# How to do debug output in Azure roles code?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, azure, azure-diagnostics

Suppose I write a console C# application - I can just use `Console.WriteLine()` to print whatever status messages and they can be read when the program is started in the console.

Now I have a Windows Azure role that runs *somewhere in the cloud* so that there's no console anymore. How do I do debug output to spot role current state and debug problems using debug output easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes I resort to something really low-tech (but instantaneous instead of waiting for diagnostics to transfer stuff): http://blog.smarx.com/posts/printf-here-in-the-cloud

Comment: +1 but I currently use service bus trace listener option that's also mentioned in your blog.  This works well because we have a monitoring application running most of the time.

Comment: Great. I spent a while trying to configure Azure Diagnostics and finally I use this approach. At least it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use System.Diagnostics.Trace - and can then set up the TraceListener to write these to Azure Diagnostics.

This won't give you real time trace, but will help to debug some situations.

For one description on this, see http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/adding-trace-event-counter-and-error.html - uses Cerebrata's tool for viewing output

Answer (score 1):

Try using [IntelliTrace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/06/07/using-intellitrace-to-debug-windows-azure-cloud-services.aspx).

I guess you have already seen the [other msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee405479.aspx) suggestions.